# iOS simulator screenshot bug

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, screenshot, simulator

I am trying to make a screenshot of my app with cmd+s.
But there is only main screen on it.
I made screenshot (cmd+shift+3) of screenshot animation >_<
Any workaround solutions?
I am forced to make pixel-perfect interface.
[image: iOS simulator screenshot bug]

Comment: If you need the screenshot according to the original screen size then you can only get the main screen. Currently it's not possible to have the device bezels along with the original display size screenshots

Answer (score 1):

You can use **CMD + SHIFT + 4** to do a screen grab as a snippet.

Using this method you can select the exact area to screenshot by clicking and dragging the area. It even shows you the pixel width and height of the area as you drag the box.

Comment: Yes, but I will get not original size screenshot.
It seems renderInContext could help.